# How can I change a calc value to a fixed value?

Tags: jquery

Suppose, I have applied in my stylesheet many times a calc() css like this:

```
div{width: calc(100% - 200px);}
div.test{height: calc(100% - 300px);}
```

but I want these width and height a fixed width like this

```
div{width: 100200px;}
div.test{height: 100300px;}
```

I need to change this with jQuery for some tricky method. But this should be changed which width is applied `calc(100% - 200px);` such as using filter function.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot change the values in the style sheet but by doing this

```
$('div').css({width:"someValue"});
```

you can achieve the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I made it and it work's succesfully:

HTML

```
<div class="testClass">

</div>
<input type="button" value="change width" onclick="testClick();"/>
```

CSS

```
.testClass
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: Green;
}
```

javascript

```
function testClick() {

    var value = "200px";
    $("div").css("width", " calc(100% - "+value+")");
}
```

Comment: I want to change the width which width is calc(100% - 200px)

Comment: What is calc? is it a function?

Comment: I understand, and I found you problem solution. I will be edit my answer soon.